# Generic value equality (identity) in C#

Tags: c#, generics

What is the best (most concise and optimal) way to compare two instances of same generic type such that **reference** types are compared for **identity** (same object, so not calling `Equals`) and **value** types for value **equality**.

Currently I do this:

```
static bool IdentityEquals<T>(T x, T y)
{
    return typeof(T).IsValueType
        ? EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, y)
        : ReferenceEquals(x, y);
}
```

Comment: Can C# overload by generic refinement?

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to just use `object.Equals` for value types:

```
 return typeof(T).IsValueType
    ? object.Equals(x, y)
    : ReferenceEquals(x, y);
```

Comment: That's slower due to boxing.

Comment: @MarcinWisnicki you did ask for "best (most concise)"

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the requirement to also include "optimal" ;-P I was really hoping for some builtin method that does identity comparisons like ReferenceEquals() but doesn't fail on value types.

Comment: @MarcinWisnicki, both ways involve boxing.

Comment: @zespri Actually the built-in value types (int, string, etc.) all implement `IEquatable<T>` which likely avoids boxing when using `EqualityComparer<T>`.

Comment: @MarcinWisnicki concise and performant may well be competing goals.  You may need to pick which one is more important.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, .NET only defines one standard virtual `Equals` method and one `GetHashCode` method even though there are two logical questions such a question could be asking (the questions are simplest if one assumes that `X` and `Y` are variables of the same type):

1. Could one replace `X` with a reference to `Y`, or vice versa, without affecting the present or future behavior of any members thereof?

   If one were to simultaneously make all references to the target of `X` point to `Y`, and all references to the target of `Y` point to `X`, would all members of `X` and `Y` continue to behave the same?

Suppose `X` and `Y` hold references to two objects of type `int[1]` which presently contain the value 42.  Some outside code holds a reference to the same instance as `Y`, and is about to increment it.  If one were to change `X` to point to the same instances as `Y`, that would change the future value of `X[0]`.

On the other hand, suppose that two objects each have a private field, each holds the one and only reference that exists anywhere in the universe to its own `int[1]`, both hold and will always hold the value 42, and neither has caused `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode()` to be invoked on that instance.  Even though `int[1]` is a mutable type, the two aforementioned instances should be considered equivalent because swapping "all references" [i.e. the only reference] to the first with all references to the second would have no effect on program behavior.  If one array held 23 and the other 27, however, swapping the references would swap which object held a reference to the 23 and which had the 27.

Note that if one adds the statement "objects of different types cannot be equivalent, since their `GetType()` methods will necessarily behave differently", then both questions above could be answered meaningfully and unambiguously for objects of any class type, and the second could be answered meaningfully for any value type.  The answers would constitute meaningful definitions of both equivalence and value equality.  The normal behavior of .NET `Equals` overrides tend to have reference types answer the first question (code is more likely interest in it) and have value types answer the second (since the first would be meaningless for them).  Since it sounds like that default behavior is what you want, perhaps you could describe if there's some situation where it isn't?

[note: a few .NET types like `Decimal` define `Equals` in loosy-goosy fashion; the two questions above would be good ones to have answered by universal virtual methods].

Answer (score 0):

Either implement **IEquatable<T>** on your types of interest, along with overrides of **object.Equals()** and **object.GetHashCode()**, or provide an instance of **IEqualityComparer<T>** to your type consumer.

*DOT NET* doesn't implement your definition of equality because then it wouldn't be mine, or Fred's down the street. Instead it provides the tools for you to build exactly what you need, without stepping on my toes or ibiting what I need to build..

Comment: Yes, the .NET Framework has a very confusing story when it comes to object equality and identity. So it's quite likely that Fred's definition would be different. See Chapter 5 of J Richter's "CLR via C#" for a way how it could have been done (by MS) less confusing.

Comment: Actually, concept of identity is [well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_%28object-oriented_programming%29) [defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_of_indiscernibles) and absolutely fundamental to implementation of popular design patterns (like Observer - you must distinguish object identity to track correct objects).